# Variables not converging... where's the error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, probability

I recently ported this code in from another language. It's supposed to run through some probability estimations and continue running through them until it converges on a solution. Convergence is determined by the maximum change in any probability getting below a certain threshold. This works perfectly in the other language. On the first iteration, the max probability change should be 50%, on the second, it should be 22%, etc. and it should converge fairly fast.

However, in javascript, it's going only two iterations before getting "stuck" and looping infinitely. I'm sure there's a VERY simple error here, but I can't seem to find it for the life of me. Any idea what's going on?

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LxLhuc0k/

```
var probs = new Array();

for (i=0; i<=99; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<=99; j++) {
        for (k=0; k<=99; k++){
            probs[i,j,k]=.5;
        }
    }
}

var maxChange=100;

while (maxChange>.01) {
    maxChange=0;

    for (i=0; i<=99; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<=99; j++) {
            for (k=0; k<=99; k++){
                oldValue=probs[i,j,k];

                probs[i,j,k]=Math.max(
                    .2125*getValue(i,j,k+1)
                    +.3900*getValue(i,j,k+5)
                    +.0920*getValue(i,j,k+10)
                    +.0370*getValue(i,j,k+15)
                    +.0560*getValue(i,j,k+20)
                    +.0008*getValue(i,j,k+25)
                    +.0016*getValue(i,j,k+40)
                    +.0001*getValue(i,j,k+60)
                    +.2100*(1-getValue(j,i,0))

                    ,1-getValue(j,i+k,0)
                );

                if (Math.abs(probs[i,j,k]-oldValue)>maxChange) maxChange=Math.abs(probs[i,j,k]-oldValue);
            }
        }
    }

    alert(maxChange);
}

alert('Done!');

function getValue(x, y, z) {
    if (x+z>99)    return(1);
    if (y>99) return(0);
    return(probs[x,y,z]);
}
```

Comment: Use console.log or console.dir instead of alert in fiddle.

Comment: From using console.log the maxchange value is always evaluating to .173537... after the second iteration. Your while loop is never false.

Comment: You know `i,j,k` will evaluate to `k`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. maxChange should be .5, then .22, then smaller, then smaller, and eventually small enough to make the condition true. This is what happens in the other language, but for some reason it's not working in the JS port.

Comment: @wumm... where are you talking about?

Comment: @JohnChrysostom `probs[i,j,k]` is the same as `probs[k]`. You are using that several times in your code.

Comment: OH DEAR LORD. probs[i][j][k] is what I want, isn't it?

Comment: @JohnChrysostom Yeah, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Wow. I use way too many languages at work... a person can go insane keeping everything straight.